# How to select value based on index on linkedhashmap

Tags: java

I have some data on linkedhasmap and i want to call first 2 data on linkedhasmap . how can i get 2 data from linkedhashmap. I just want call value 1 and value 2.

here the code

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

    map.put(1, "value 1");
    map.put(2, "value 2");
    map.put(3, "value 3");

    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()){

      for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
              if (entry.getKey().equals(i)){

        System.out.println(entry.getValue(i));

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code like this to get the first two values, `LinkedHashMap` is ordered and preserves the order of insertion.

```java
int count = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  if (count == 2) {
    break;
  }
  System.out.println(entry.getValue());
  count++;
}
```